# Am I protected from vampire landlords?

Tags: vampire, laws, the-vampire-diaries

According to Vampire Diaries, vampires need to be invited by the owner of the home to enter.  But what if my landlord is a vampire?  In the UK, if I am a leasehold owner of an apartment, I am one of the owners of the apartment, but the vampire landlord still maintains a freehold ownership of the apartment [[source](http://www.moneyunder30.com/renters-rights)].  If the vampire has an ownership of the apartment, does he need my permission to enter?

Comment: Different vampire series have different ideas. Some would say that the resident controls the apartment or home and others would claim the owner of the building always has "permission" to enter. Consider many rental contracts explicitly give the landlord the right to enter the property.

Comment: Speaking as a landlord, rental contracts SAY a lot of things that aren't necessarily allowed by law, and the law of the land wins.  In Maryland, for example, a landlord needs to give 24 hours notice of intent to entry unless in case of emergency.  However, there's no suggestion I can think of in either True Blood (TV) or the Southern Vampire Chronicles (Books) that the law has any relevance.

Comment: Vampires cannot own property in the vampire diaries series, so they give their houses to living relatives so that it has protections against other vampires. True blood it appears they can own property, which would probably allow the vampire into your apartment.

Comment: This one is actually pretty easy to answer. Since protection seems to be a function of legal property rights, and since [a vampire can't legally own property](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Invitation) (what with being dead), then a vampire can't be a landlord.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vampire Diaries is somewhat unusual in that its conceit over the ability to block vampires from entering a property (the "[invitation](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Invitation)") are very much based on **legal property rights**. You can, for example block a vampire from entering a property that they had previously been invited to by signing the deeds over to another person. If the vampire is in the house at the time, they'll even be forcefully ejected, as we can see from this sequence from "[Never Let Me Go](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Never_Let_Me_Go)"

[image]

Since under UK and US law (as depicted in Vampire Diaries, as well as in real life), **a [dead person can't own property](http://blog.landregistry.gov.uk/property-owner-dies/)**, there is no set of circumstances where a genuine vampire could be the legal landlord of your property, and hence have an automatic right of entry.